# Want to do IGenericInterface<T> where T : ISomethingElse<typeof(this)> //i.e. typeof the implementing class

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I want to use the `this` keyword or something like `typeof(this)` in the `where` restriction of my generic interface but apparently that's not correct (neither compiles).  Is there a slick way to do this that I don't know about?

```
interface IParent<TChild> where TChild : IChildOf<typeof(this)>
{

    void AddRange(TChild children){}

}

interface IChildOf<TParent> : IDisposable
{
    TParent Parent { get; }
}
```

Or do I have to do

```
interface IParent<TChild, T2> where TChild : IChildOf<T2>
```

and just know that T2 will be the class implementing the interface?

Comment: `this` is meaningless in the context where you are trying to use.

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to accomplish? A tree stucture where each node has multiple children?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curiously recurring generic pattern can be used here:

```
interface IParent<TChild, TParent>
  where TChild : IChildOf<TParent>
  where TParent : IParent<TChild, TParent>
{
  void AddRange(TChild children);
}
```

But I'd [seriously consider re-evaluating your design](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx). Do you really *need* this?

Comment: +1 and marked answered, I ended up just removing TParnet altogether and doing only IParent<TChild>.  Thanks.

Comment: @dFlat: Glad to hear of your design change. I've done C# for years, heavily using generics, but only used the CRGP once. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your only choice is:

```
interface IParent<TChild, TParent> where TChild : IChildOf<TParent>
{
    void AddRange(TChild children);
}
```

You can only use the type parameters or known compile time types in the type constraints to your generic interface, so this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want to build a tree structure where each node has multiple children. You can do it like this:

```
interface INode
{
    List<INode> Children { get; }
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<INode> children);
}

class Node : INode
{
    List<INode> Children { get; private set; }

    void AddRange(IEnumerable<INode> children)
    {
        Children.AddRange(children);
    }
}
```